# How to profile CPU used by method/function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cpu-usage, profiler

The app I'm developing does some intensive processing and I'd like to understand where the time is being used. The Time Profiler in Instruments shows the tree of calls but I can't see how to get the information I need.

My app has a structure like this:

```
A
 B
  B1
   E1
  B2
  B3
   E1
 C
  C1
  C2
   E1
  C3
 D
  D1
  D2
   E1
```

Now, method E1 is called from a number of places and I'd like to see how much CPU it is using. However, from the profiler output I can only see the time taken in E1 down each branch of the tree. Is there any way of getting a report by method/function regardless of where it is called from? e.g. Sum the total time spent in E1?

Thanks,

Julian

Comment: Did you try profiling using instruments?

Answer (score 0):

The link posted by naglerrr is the answer - [How to measure total time spent in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017519/how-to-measure-total-time-spent-in-a-function)

You need to find the function in the profiler tree, right click and select "Focus on Calls Made By". Check the linked answer for more information.